# Is it possible to add fields and subcollection both at once in firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a requirement to add fields and collection both in a firebase document.
It has structure like this:

```
room
 - roomid
   - ownerId (document field)
   - messages (subcollection)
     - messageId
      - content
```

I have seen the document and able to add fields and subcollection separately in the room/roomid reference.
I am considering following links:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#hierarchical-data
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#web-version-9_1

My question is, is it possible to add both ownerId and messages subcollection in 1 go?

My code looks like this:

```
const ref = await addDoc(collection(db, 'room'), {ownerId: id});
await addDoc(collection(db, 'room', ref.id, 'messages'), {content});
```

Answer (score 0):

To write both documents in a single atomic operation, you'll need to change two things:

- Use `doc()` and `setDoc()` instead of `addDoc()`, so that you can determine the new document's ID before it is written to the database. You can find an example of this in the first code snippet of the documentation on [adding a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document).
- Put both write operations in a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes), so that they are sent to and committed on the database in atomically.

In code that'd be something like:

```
const batch = writeBatch(db);

const roomRef = doc(collection(db, "room"));
batch.set(roomRef, {ownerId: id});

const messageRef = doc(collection(db, 'room', roomRef.id, 'messages'));
batch.set(messageRef, {content});

await batch.commit();
```

Comment: 1. I will need to query the room collection to find the last document id to determine new id. Which will count as 1 more read operation. That is why using addDoc.
2. I suppose, it will take same time as in my solution, so it will wait for first operation to complete to get roomId and then use it for second, am I right? Is there any benefit of using this solution over individual operation which I am doing without batch?

Comment: 1. The code I shared does not need to read the `room` to determine its ID. `doc(collection(db, "room"))` is a pure client-side operation.  2. Yes, this is atomic: so either both writes succeed or neither of them does. If you don't need that, you can use the same approach without a batched write. In that case, see the link in the first bullet point.

Comment: My point 1 was my comment to your first bullet point actually. Anyways, I got it with your answer, that its not possible to do both at the same time. Would need batch for first message only, from next message, would need to enter messages in the collection inside roomId. Thanks for your help.